# How to create a 2d array with only two elements and randomize it?

Tags: javascript

I've created a 2d array where `subArrays` include only `0` and `1` generated via `Math.random()` function. Currently it's implemented  with `for loops`.
Now I'm trying to get the same output using `es6` functions, but could't solve it.

Here is the solution with for loops

```js
const rows = 25;
const cols = 35;

const randomGrid = () => {
  const grid = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    const row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      row.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
    }
    grid.push(row);
  }
  return grid;
};

console.log(randomGrid())
```

And here I am trying to achieve the same output with modern js functions.
I managed only two create the `2d Array`, but could't populate with `0` and `1` in random order. Currently elements are `undefined`.

```js
const rows = 25;
const cols = 35;

const randomTwoDArr = (numOfRows, numOfCols) => {
  const grid = [];
  return Array(numOfRows)
    .fill()
    .map((row) => Array(numOfCols));
};

console.log(randomTwoDArr(rows, cols));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) as:

```js
const rows = 25;
const cols = 35;

const randomGrid = () => {
    return Array.from({ length: rows }, () => {
        return Array.from({ length: cols }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
    });
};

console.log(randomGrid());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, Just complete creating columns with `Array(numOfCols).fill()` and fill it with random numbers *1 or 0* `.map(x=>Math.floor(Math.random() * 2))`

```js
const rows = 25;
const cols = 35;

const randomTwoDArr = (numOfRows, numOfCols) => {
  const grid = [];
  return Array(numOfRows)
    .fill()
    .map((row) => Array(numOfCols).fill().map(x=>Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)));
};

console.log(randomTwoDArr(rows, cols));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Array.from`

```js
const rows = 25;
const cols = 35;

const randomTwoDArr = (numOfRows, numOfCols) => {
  const grid = [];
  return Array.from({length:numOfRows}, _ => Array.from({length:numOfCols }, () => Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1: 0))
    
};

console.log(randomTwoDArr(rows, cols));
```